# HTML Form embedded in <table> tag is not rendered properly?

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I have following simple HTML form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">
        <form name="logon" method="post" id="logon" action="take.php">
          <tr>
                <td tabindex="0">User ID </td>
                <td>
                        <input name="login"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="" title="User ID">
                </td>
                <td class="loginlabel">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                <td tabindex="0">Password </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="lable">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                 <td colspan="3">
                    <p class="pushButton"><button type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
                </td>
          </tr>

        </form>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this page in any browser and inspect element, I found weird structure of the HTML form. I found `<form>` tag immediately closed after start,
please find the screen shot of html form inspection,
[image: Image of HTML form inspection embedded in <table> tag]

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, when you open a tag within another tag, the tag you open (in your case the `<form>` tag) gets clsoed when its parent gets closed.

Therefore (for example):

```
<p><form></p>
<p></form></p>
```

will result in the following:

```
<p><form></form></p>
<p></p>
```

This is because, according to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) (which sets international standards on HTML among other things), the only context a form element can be used in is where [flow content](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#flow-content-2) can be expected. Flow content are most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications, for example:
[image: Flow content]

---

**The solution to this is to place the form tags above that of the table, encasing the table in the form as below:**

```
<form>
   <table>
   </table>
</form>
```

---

***To clarify:***
You need to be sure that the *table* is **inside** the *form* tags. See a complete example as working below:

```
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="logon" method="post" id="logon" action="take.php">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">
        <tr>
          <td tabindex="0">User ID </td>
          <td>
            <input name="login" maxlength="12" size="15" value="" title="User ID">
          </td>
          <td class="loginlabel">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td tabindex="0">Password </td>
          <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="12" size="15" value="">
          </td>
          <td class="lable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <p class="pushButton">
              <button type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Using the inspect function in Chrome proves that the output to the browser shows the table nested inside of the form tags:
[image: Updated inspect]

---

Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: In my case, where the parent tag of `form>` is closed? it is closed just before `<form>` is closed, So How in my case its a problem?

Comment: The parent tag of `<form>` is `<table>` (as the form is nested inside the table) - in order to correct your error you need to 'swap' these roles and nest the `<table>` inside the `<form>`. I have updated my original answer to clarify slightly.

Comment: Still my question is WHY? Why it is mandatory to provide `<table>` tag withing `<form>`? Why reverse is not working properly?

Comment: @BSalunke - I have updated the original post to hopefully provide some insight into why a form cannot nest inside a table. For future issues, try using the W3C validator to figure out issues like this (https://validator.w3.org/). If your issue has been solved then please mark an answer as correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Move the `table` tags inside of the form also:

```
<form name="logon" method="post" id="logon" action="take.php">
     <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">
          <tr>
                <td tabindex="0">User ID </td>
                <td>
                        <input name="login"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="" title="User ID">
                </td>
                <td class="loginlabel">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                <td tabindex="0">Password </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="lable">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                 <td colspan="3">
                    <p class="pushButton"><button type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
                </td>
          </tr>

   </table>
</form>
```

The reason for this could just be that the form is unsure why there are `tr` tags without a `table` tag within it. It seems a strange limitation however maybe somebody else can clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

you have this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">
    <form name="logon" method="post" id="logon" action="take.php">
```

You need to declare first the form and then the table

```
<form name="logon" method="post" id="logon" action="take.php">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">
      <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">User ID </td>
            <td>
                    <input name="login"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="" title="User ID">
            </td>
            <td class="loginlabel">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">Password </td>
            <td>
                    <input type="password" name="password"  maxlength="12" size="15" value="">
            </td>
            <td class="lable">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
             <td colspan="3">
                <p class="pushButton"><button type="submit" form="nameform" value="Submit">Submit</button></p>
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: So you have the form, and inside that form you will have the login table. We can use a modern day example... You get inside of your bed, not the bed inside of you! :D